# Tengo una función en el modelo php, pero no devuelve resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito mostrar datos de una tabla en la vista, es algo sencillo, algo que siempre he hecho y siempre me ha salido, pero ahora no se que pasa, lo he vuelto a rehacer y nada, me devuelve un array vacío, pero cuando pongo la misma consulta en la base de datos si me devuelve el resultado que quiero.

Les paso todo, desde la llamada, quizás algo se me está pasando:

El Javascript:

```
var fechaActual = $('#txtFechaActual').val();

function showEntradasHoy() {
    var ajaxUrl = base_url + "Caja/getEntradasHoy";
    var data = { 'fechaActual': fechaActual };


    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: 'post',
        data: data, 
        success: function(responses) {
            console.log(responses);
        }
    });
}

showEntradasHoy();
```

El controlador:

```
class Caja extends Controllers
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getEntradasHoy()
    {
        $fechaActual = $_POST["fechaActual"];

        $arrData = $this -> model -> selectEntradasHoy($fechaActual);
        print_r($arrData);
    }

}
```

El modelo:

```
class CajaModel extends Mysql
{

    public $fecEntrada;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function selectEntradasHoy(string $fecha) {

        $this -> fecEntrada = $fecha;

        $sql = "SELECT A.codigo AS codigo, A.fecha AS fecha, A.entrada AS codEntrada, B.nombre AS nomEntrada FROM entradas_select A INNER JOIN entradas B ON B.codigo = A.entrada WHERE A.fecha = '{$this -> fecEntrada}'";
        $request = $this -> SelectAll($sql);

        return $request;

    }

 }
```

Como dije al comienzo, ya hice un console.log de la consulta y tal cual la pongo en el phpmyadmin para ver si hay algún error en la consulta y ahí si me devuelve el resultado, pero en la programación sólo me devuelve un array vacío.

Espero que me puedan dar una mano. Mil gracias desde ya.

Comment: Pues depura tu código. Pon un `var_dump($this -> fecEntrada);` en `selectEntradasHoy()` y dinos qué muestra. También, convendría ver lo que tienes en `SelectAll()` y saber si estás controlando que la conexión a la BD sea válida.

Comment: Efectivamente, era la conexión a la BD, había puesto mal el nombre de la BD, muchísimas gracias, no se me pasó por la cabeza revisar eso.

Comment: Moraleja: implementa control de errores en tu código, también eventuales errores de lógica. Por ejemplo, no pases a usar la conexión sin antes verificar que esta sea válida: `if ($conexion) { //usar la conexion } else { //emitir un mensaje de error para incorporarlo a tu política de manejo de errores }` Mientras no implementes manejo de errores no tendrás un programa maduro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, definitivamente lo voy a hacer